# Will stored procedure increases the performance of application and Ideal scenarios to use them?

Tags: mysql, rdbms

In our company, we don't really use stored procedures because it makes the code not flexible to debug, update in case of errors and modification in database columns which takes lot of time. **I would like to know the ideal scenarios to use stored procedure in enterprise-level applications with some examples? or is it bad to use stored proc?**

And If I want to run 6 different queries I need to make 5 calls to the database. But if I have the stored proc I can do all these things in one single call, **Will this make a significant improvement in the performance when using in this situation?** (because I heard like every query will be catch by MySQL/sql so query execution plan is there with both SQL queries and stored procedure in catch which makes no difference in performance) pl give your valid opinions!

Thank you for your answer!
I really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A stored procedure does directly not make individual queries any faster, but it does allow some other benefits performance-wise:

- If your queries are complex enough (multiple ones). SP's can perform better by reducing the back and forth communication between client and the server by storing intermediate results in temp tables etc.
- Having very complex queries can sometimes be optimized by breaking queries into smaller ones (again, using temp tables). SP's offer nice way of encapsulating this into the db.

Comment: Sometimes when you have very complex queries, you may achieve better performance by breaking a large query to smaller pieces (helping optmizer to choose better access to data). These intermediate results can be put to temporary tables (tables that live only the execution of the procedure). See documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html.

Comment: What are temp table? what do you mean by intermediate results?  pls, explain.

But having like  6 queries in DB debugging, modifying.. and also makes the application rigid meaning we don't if SP is  referred in other SP, difficult to debug the issue in code.

If we have an SP(stored procedure) that has 6 SQL statements, if I make those calls without SP how much time difference will I have approx ?

Comment: See previous comment. If you have a specific question please post it as a new question with code as this one has been closed.